# Invoke Multiple Lambdas using AWS step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I have two lambdas L1 and L2. Iam starting state machine in L1. I have environment variable for L1 i.e.,E1. Basically E1 is list of space separated values for which I need to do some Hashfunction in L1 and for each value I need to trigger a separate instance of Lambda L2 with that value and Hash(value) as input

eg: E1 - "1 2 3"
and hash(1) = stack, hash(2) = over, hash(3) = flow
Three instances of L2 should be triggered with (i, hash(i)) as input/payload to L2

How to achieve this using step functions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a `Map` state. The easiest way would be to have the output of the first function be an array of the inputs to the second. So something like this:

```json
[
  {
    i: 1,
    iHash: 'hashed 1'
  },
  {
    i: 2,
    iHash: 'hashed 2'
  }
  .
  .
  .
]
```

In the `Map` state you set the `iterator` value to the array from the output. The value of each element of the array will be the input to the first state inside the `Map` state. Inside the `Map` state you just need to have another `Task` state that is your second Lambda function, and pass in `$` to the `Payload`.